# Differentiating the $\sin(\log({t^T}{t}))$

Tags: solution-verification, vector-analysis

So I am wanting to check whether or not I have done the correct differentiation of the following function:

$$\sin(\log({\mathbf t^T}{\mathbf t}))  \quad \text{where } \mathbf t \in R^D$$

Obviously using the chain rule I have ended up with the following:

$$\frac{2\mathbf t}{{\mathbf t^T}{\mathbf t}}\cos(\log({\mathbf t^T}{\mathbf t}))$$

Please note that the bold is signifying vectors.
If I have done this wrong should I instead be computing the Jacobian?

Comment: Looks good. I would just add $\mathbf{t}\neq 0$ as a condition.

Comment: Will do, thank you